# Error Symfony installation " The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to create a new Symfony project.
When I launch the installer: `symfony new sitepro --version=6.0.* --webapp`
The installation start but then there is 2 errors:

```
      [RuntimeException]
  The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems): ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\User
  s\Shiyo\Desktop\Pro\Projets\sitepro/vendor/composer/b67ec329/php-fig-cache-aa5030c/LICENSE.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied



  [ErrorException]
  ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\Shiyo\Desktop\Pro\Projets\sitepro/vendor/composer/b67ec329/php-fig-cache-aa5030c/LICENSE.txt): Failed to open stream: Pe
  rmission denied

 unable to run C:\composer\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\Shiyo\Desktop\Pro\Projets\sitepro 6.0.* --no-interaction
```

I'm working on Windows 10, php 8.1.6.
I tried `composer clearcache`, to uninstall and install 7-Zip and I have all the permissions for this folder so I really don't get why I have this error.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: At first sight there are two possible reasons for this problem:

Do you have write/edit rights on the "sitepro" folder and so for these child like the vendor subdirectory ?

Was the "sitepro" folder empty? Did you try to start from scratch by deleting it entirely and retrying?

Comment: This is likely a Symfony console application, add `-vvv` for debugging output like `symfony -vvv new sitepro --version=6.0.* --webapp` - it is a global option.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the Desktop folder of Windows. It has special rights. I tried on an other folder and it work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a permissions issue on the folder. Basically, you can't write to that folder due to one of the following reasons:

1. There is a process that is using the folder. For instance, if xampp is running and you are trying to create a new project in htdocs, you will most likely encounter this error because xampp is using the folder. Solution is to close whichever application is using the folder and you should be able to write to that folder without any problems.
2. The user you are using has insufficient permissions to the folder. Solution is to use a privileged user or find a way to give your user write permissions to the folder.