# Install of laravel/breeze failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

Using desktop docker and WSL on windows using Laravel breeze with react - encountering some errors

```
(To create my Laravel app)
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

cd example-app

code .

./vendor/bin/sail up -d

./vendor/bin/sail composer --version

./vendor/bin/sail composer require laravel/breeze --dev  (this line fails)


The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
Install of laravel/breeze failed
```

In ZipDownloader.php line 223:

The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems): ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/ht
ml/vendor/composer/6270341f/laravel-breeze-1cb124f/LICENSE.md): Operation failed: Operation not permitted

In ZipDownloader.php line 210:

ZipArchive::extractTo(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/6270341f/laravel-breeze-1cb124f/LICENSE.md): Operation failed: Operation not permitted

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Is this the **full** error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase edited it to show more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Symfony installation " The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72557472/error-symfony-installation-the-archive-may-contain-identical-file-names-with-d)